# Which is faster: multiple queries with less results or returning all and getting php to process

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm busy with a paging component for my framework and I'm wondering which of the following 2 is faster (or if there is a better solution even better).

My thinking here is to have my object do the following in this order:

1. Get current page and results per page from GET variables
2. Get total amount of results for display purposes (showing 10 of 534 results)
3. Determine which results to get based on current page and results per page.
4. Return results to view to display and build paging class

From what I can see I have one of 2 options:

**Multiple queries with less results**

1. Do a query to determine row count for all results.
2. Do another query to return the results which I need for the active page using offset

**One query and have PHP do the processing**

1. Return all rows to an array
2. Get PHP to return the rows from the array and do a count()

Which would be faster to do? I understand the more results the better for option 1, but it still feels like 2 queries to count rows and then return certain results still feels faster than just 1 query which returns all results and get PHP to do the rest of the processing.

Is there another more sufficient way I am missing perhaps?

Comment: It's impossible to tell you because neither option is faster in all cases. Benchmark both options and get on with your life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Test it.

We don't know what your framework is doing, how your database is structured, or how much processing your PHP code does with the data.  Code the core items of both, and run a test on the same mock data set.

If you really want to go to town, run a set of tests on a series of placeholder data, with various load-testing items.  You are making a "framework", after all, so you may as well find out what works.

#### And my own personal opinion:

If the PHP code is a full-page render, or done inside an individual session, go for an internal SQL view to get the pages.  Only store the data entirely in PHP if you're going to have a *.php file that's used by multiple sessions at once, and could avoid a database round-trip by doing so.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `MySQLi` you can have the results remain in `MySQL` (`MYSQLI_USE_RESULT`) and have `PHP` read them one by one in order to avoid overloading `PHP`'s memory.

All the info you want is here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

**Note:**

If you use `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT` all subsequent calls will return **error** `Commands out of sync` unless you call `mysqli_free_result()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using your first approach with one query to get the count (using MySQL's `COUNT` function, not PHP's `mysql_num_rows` or similar) and another query to just select the rows you need for the current page given the arguments for offset and results per page.